# Multicollinearity Market mix modeling

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, ridge-regression, marketing

I want to know what can be the best approach to handle multicollinearity. I am building a regression model with just 4 independent but all important variables and am not able to control the VIF.

Should I ignore the high VIF because all variables do have an important contribution in my sales as per the business logic? or should I go for ridge regression?

Comment: What's the purpose of your model?  For some purposes multicollinearity is not an issue and for others it's important.

Comment: I am working on building market mix modeling to understand the impact of advertisement on different media channels on my sales and as per my business logic, all channels have a positive impact on my sales.